# How to make a iPhone app using both phone gap and native app

Tags: iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have being developing `iPhone` native application for last 2 year. But now I am trying to learn `phone gap`. I have seen the sample of phone gap which use `index.html` as a start page, But I want to make an app with both `native` as well as `phone gap`.So can any one guide me how to use  the native components like `viewController`, `navigationBar`, `tabBarController` component and phone gap. Also if you have any tutorial which will be helpful for me I have see many tutorial  but all are old which doesn't run on my Xcode 4.5.

Comment: I asked this 6 weeks ago with more examples of what I already tried.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of plugin you can use native code in phone gap
for example I am pasting some code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>

@interface PushToken : CDVPlugin
{
    NSString* callbackID; 
}


@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* callbackID;

- (void) getToken:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;




@end


#import "PushToken.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation PushToken

@synthesize callbackID;

-(void)getToken:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options  {
    self.callbackID = [arguments pop];

    NSString *token = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).token;
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:[token stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if(token.length != 0)
    {
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }else {    
        [self writeJavascript: [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
    }
}

@end


.js file

var PushToken = {
getToken: function(types, success, fail) {
    return cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushToken", "getToken", types);
}
};


including .js file
<script src="PushToken.js"></script>


calling

PushToken.getToken(     
                           ["getToken"] ,           
                           function(token) {
                           devToken = token;
                           //navigator.notification.alert(devToken);
                           },
                           function(error) {
                           navigator.notification.alert("Error :Token Not Found "+error);      
                           }
                           );

may be helpful
thanks
```

Comment: But I am very new to it can you please guide me how to call this class  also how to call the method as we like to do for native app.

Answer (score 0):

for Native features you can make use of plugins and can even create by yourself

[phonegap plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone)

[How to create plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

You can also refer to [THIS](http://hiediutley.com/) blog